Why is the Mobile Render Delay so high for the LCP (Largest contentful paint)
With Lighthouse / Google Pagespeed I get a really high "Render delay" when testing for mobile. For desktop everything is all good.
Tested this in a clean browser with lighthouse. Get the same results with Google pagespeed.
Not sure where to specifical look for the solution. Any tools that investigate this more?


Is this page client-side rendered? If it uses JS to render the paragraph, the mobile emulation would slow down the download/execution of the script, affecting the LCP performance. A link to the page would be helpful to debug it further.
